# is it possible to add a relative path to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I want to use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to load the context from xml configuration files. The files are stored in a subfolder of a "ConfigFilesFolder".

1) "ConfigFilesFolder" is already a part of classpath and I can load any xml file present in that folder.

ex: `context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("someconfiguration.xml");`

in the above I am passing the name of file as a string and works well.

My Requirement is :

> `ConfigFilesFolder/somesubfolder`

`newcontext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("someconfiguration.xml");`

I want to load the files from subfolder (somesubFolder) of "ConfigFilesFolder" using  `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("nameofFile.xml")`.

where someconfiguration.xml is a part of somesubFolder.

PS: I cannot use the `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` bcz of some restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use folders in classpath - the entries in the classpath are the "root", and any folder in them can be relatively accessed, so in your case:

```
newcontext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/somesubfolder/someconfiguration.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine for me. I guess I was missing an initial file separator which is fine now.